# Self-contained Asp.net core (1.0.1) app cannot find RestSharp dll

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-4.6

I have an ASP.Net Core (1.0.1) web app. One of the packages it consumes itself consumes RestSharp. When built, the RestSharp dll is indeed in the app root. But when I deploy and browse to the app, I get the following error:

> Application startup exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=105.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d483824b1b4e30c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   File name: 'RestSharp, Version=105.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d483824b1b4e30c'.

**Let me be clear, here... the dll is the correct version: 105.2.3.0.**

Now, if I register RestSharp to the GAC, all is well and the website works. But this is a .Net Core self-contained app and it shouldn't be looking in the GAC at all (should it??).

I'm really lost and confused. I honestly don't know what's going on, so I really could do with some help.

App folder after publishing:

MyApp/
    MyApp.exe
    ....
    ....
    etc.
    RestSharp.dll (v105.2.3.0)
    web.config
    appsettings.json

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I should have also mentioned that I'm targetting net46.

Comment: You shouldn't use GAC or any other things (runtime loaders, etc) as you have NuGet packages. Let me be clear, here... You can create an asp.net core app, then you right click -> manage NuGet packages for this solution -> Browse -> Restsharp -> v.105.2.3 -> Install and it should be sufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Only when I register it to the GAC does the app work.

Comment: RestSharp doesn't run on .NET Core yet. I tried it with the compatibility layer which worked fine when hitting a localhost endpoint but failed when using any other endpoint. I suggest you look for the branch that they're working on that adds .NET Core support, or pick a different client such as HttpClient.

Comment: @mason: sorry, see my update above - I'm targetting net46.

Comment: There is RestSharp.NetCore v 105.2.3 or you can get a prerelease that's now at 105.2.4-rc4-24214-01.

Comment: You said "This is a .NET Core self contained app". But that's not true if you're targeting .NET Framework 4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mason rightly pointed out: You said "This is a .NET Core self contained app". But that's not true if you're targeting .NET Framework 4.6.